# Nginx IFSC Code Script with Wordpress Sub-directory Page Not Found

Tags: wordpress, nginx

This is working

```
https://example.com/ifsc-code/index.php?bank=axis-bank&state=west-bengal&district=kolkata&branch=bally
```

This is showing error404

```
https://example.com/ifsc-code/axis-bank/west-bengal/kolkata/bally
```

I am using this code in Nginx.conf file

```
location /ifsc-code {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3&branch=$4;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?bank=$1&state=$2;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/?$ /index.php?bank=$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and my problem has solved, hope it will help someone.

```
location  /ifsc-code {
                 root /var/www/example/ifsc-code; 
                 index index.php index.html index.htm;
                 try_files $uri $uri/ @ifsc-code;
}
        
location @ifsc-code {
                rewrite ^/ifsc-code/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /ifsc-code/index.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3&branch=$4;
                rewrite ^/ifsc-code/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /ifsc-code/index.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3;
                rewrite ^/ifsc-code/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /ifsc-code/index.php?bank=$1&state=$2;
                rewrite ^/ifsc-code/(.*)/?$ /ifsc-code/index.php?bank=$1;
}
```